# Is there an upper limit on the message size for snowflake connector for kafka connect?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

The use case is that whenever there is a large message(> 1MB), we store it on S3 and the Kafka events that gets generated just point to these messages via the URL.

So, before sending data to snowflake via this connector, I want to use an SMT to download the actual large messages from S3 URLs. Is there an upper limit on the snowflake [connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-install.html#installing-and-configuring-the-kafka-connector) that I should be aware of?

Answer (score -1):

By default, the Kafka brokers can handle messages up to 1MB (actually a little less than 1MB) with the default configuration settings,  however please note that Kafka is optimized for small messages of about 1K. You can change it but it is not a good practice to send large messages to kafka. One option is if you can compress or split the message. Please take a look at the below configurations in kafka

message.max.bytes

replica.fetch.max.bytes

fetch.message.max.bytes

max.request.size

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more directed towards the snowflake connector. As mentioned, we're handling large messages by storing the actual message on s3 and passing around the S3 URL in the kafka message. Sorry if the question is not clear.

Comment: Snowflake Connector is nothing but a type of kafka connector(Sync/Source). Instead of you writing the producer and consumer yourself, it has been abstracted in the connector, so it will have the same kafka configuration requirement if you have to write your own producer and consumer